# Detecting change of 'ComboBox' selected item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a [`ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) whose items I have populated from a database. I wish to know if the selected item has changed from when I initially displayed the `ComboBox`. How can I determine this?

Comment: [`ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, thats the event

Answer (score 0):

it is not simple- try to handle EndEdit event/ But you couldnot handle select change in dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the default value in the .Tag property and comparing the two whenever you need.